# Google Spreadsheet into JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, excel

[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvwpv.png)

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGJU5FJVmKI3A5A3NFY-XQU7MlBOG0VmvUIZvx8Bitg/edit#gid=72338765)

Assume I have the `Google Spreadsheet` (Google Doc). How could I extract those elements and put it under a `JSON` format? I'd like to obtain

```
{
test1: { element1: price1,
          element2: price2,
          element3: price3,
        },
test2: { anotherele1: anotherprice1,
         anotherele2: anotherprice2,
         anotherele3: anotherprice3,
       },
test3: { aaa: 111,
        bbb: 345,
        ccc: 678,
       }, 
}
```

In fact, I would like my code to detect this kind of structure to reformat it under that kind of `JSON` structure. How could I do such thing in `JavaScript` with **what I have done so far**?

```
  var SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EYUQ-6zXfK2_kxMMbgjlOW0KXJRc-ejD/view";

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  var data = sheet.getRange("A:C").getValues();
```

**P.S.**  I need to create a script I will put in `Google-Adwords` which will manage every MaxCPC for every accounts and campaigns from a single `Google-Spreadsheet`. Here is an [example](http://www.freeadwordsscripts.com/2013/02/update-your-bids-from-google-spreadsheet.html) of what it looks like, but I am a bit confused how to format it as a JSON dictionary.

### UPDATE

For @Paul

```
[[test1, element1, price1], [, element2, price2], [, element3, price3], [, , ], [test2, anotherele1, anotherprice1], [, anotherele2, anotherprice2], [, anotherele3, anotherprice3], [, , ], [test3, aaa, 123.0], [, bbb, 345.0], [, ccc, 678.0], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ], [, , ]]
{}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [How To Export Google Sheets Data To JSON And XML](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/how-to-export-google-sheets-data-to-json-and-xml/)

Comment: It is not what I want @PeterT. I need to create a script I will put in Google-Adwords which will manage every accounts and campaigns from a single Google-Spreadsheet.

Comment: Your link has access denied.

Comment: Nope, it's prompting me to request access still.

Comment: Also, which of the clients are you using? That doesn't look like the Google-provided module.

Comment: Nope, still prompting for access.

Comment: Nope, no change.

Comment: Can you just print above what is in the `data` variable after you call `getValues()` on that line?

Comment: Yep, took me a bit to write it up with samples.  Check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the thing to recognize here is that you've basically created a data structure in your spreadsheet that a spreadsheet isn't used to.  Spreadsheets deal in rows and columns, your structure makes blank lines significant and implies a group based on blank cells.  So your parsing of that data needs to impose that awareness on the data you get back.

In English, what you need to do is iterate on the outer array, then peek at each element to figure out if you're starting a new group or ending a group.  As well as detecting when you have no more data. My proposed rules based on your sample data:

- You're starting a group if the inner array has three non-blank elements.
- You're in an existing group when they have three elements but the first is an empty string.
- You're ending a group if you hit an array where all the elements are blank
- You're ending the data if there are two consecutive arrays where all elements are blank.

Ok, so I have made some functions to help with this.  It's a bit simplified. The second two rules are kind of irrelevant if your data stays the way it is now, so I skipped them.

It's probably not optimized and so you'll need to tweak for edge cases, but this should give you the general approach:

```
function isBlank(line) {
    // TODO: from the sample data, this will work; but you might add more cases in the future
    return line[0].trim() === '' && line[1].trim() === '';
}

function parseData(data) {
    // TODO: validate data coming in

    const output = {};
    let currentGroupName = '';

    data.forEach(line => {
        // TODO: better validation

        // Might be worth pre-processing to trim out the blank rows, right now this will just ignore blank lines
        if (isBlank(line)){
            return; 
        }

        if (line[0].trim().length > 0) {
            currentGroupName = line[0].trim();
        }

        // create an object if there isn't one
        output[currentGroupName] = output[currentGroupName] || {};

        output[currentGroupName][line[1]] = line[2];
    });

    return output;
}

module.exports = parseData;
```

I ran it with your sample data and here's what I got:

```
> var data = [['test1', 'element1', 'price1'], ['', 'element2', 'price2'], ['', 'element3', 'price3'], ['','' ,'' ], ['test2', 'anotherele1', 'anotherprice1'], ['', 'anotherele2', 'anotherprice2'], ['', 'anotherele3', 'anotherprice3'], ['', '', ''], ['test3', 'aaa', 123.0], ['', 'bbb', 345.0], ['', 'ccc', 678.0], ['', '', ''], ['','' , '']]
undefined
> var parse = require('./parseData')
undefined
> parse(data)
{ test1: { element1: 'price1', element2: 'price2', element3: 'price3' },
  test2:
   { anotherele1: 'anotherprice1',
     anotherele2: 'anotherprice2',
     anotherele3: 'anotherprice3' },
  test3: { aaa: 123, bbb: 345, ccc: 678 } }
>
```

Comment: What is you last black? How did you test out? It seems like ipython, but obviously, it is not.

Comment: ? my last black?

Comment: This is just the node console.  I saved my functions in a module then opened up the node console to try it out.

Comment: Yes, with the '>'

Comment: It's just the next line in the console. It's a prompt for the next command I want to give it.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine!! I appreciate a lot btw and I understand better how to do it. I am dealing with python since a couple of months now and I have to say that combining python with javascript is really powerful!!!